# It seems it is a bit slow to extract element from a List in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I just wrote a Rcpp function with three same size input vectors, `x`(numeric) `y`(numeric) and `category`(character). Then I want to return a list, the list size is equal to the length of unique category values. Each element in this list is a same size matrix (equal rows and columns) based on `x` and `y` with corresponding category.

However, I found my code is not fast enough when the size of `n` is huge. I think the reason is I need to extract something from the list, do some computation and insert it back every time. Does anyone have suggestions on how to speed up the process.

**Rcpp code**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
List myList(NumericVector x, NumericVector y, CharacterVector category) {

  int n = x.size();
  CharacterVector levels = unique(category);
  int levels_size = levels.size();
  List L(levels_size);

  int plot_width = 600;
  int plot_height = 600;

  // Each element in the list L has the same size Matrix
  for(int j = 0; j < levels_size; j++) {
    NumericMatrix R(plot_height, plot_width);
    L[j] = R;
  }
  int id = 0;

  double xmax = max(x);
  double ymax = max(y);
  double xmin = min(x);
  double ymin = min(y);

  for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {

    for(int j = 0; j < levels_size; j++) {
      if(category[i] == levels[j]) {
        id = j;
        break;
      }
    }

    int id_x = floor((x[i] - xmin)/(xmax - xmin) * (plot_width - 1));
    int id_y = floor((y[i] - ymin)/(ymax - ymin) * (plot_height - 1));

    NumericMatrix M = L[id];
    // some computation in M
    M(id_y, id_x) += 1;
    L[id] = M;
  }
  return(L);
}
```

**R code**

```
n <- 1e8
class <- 20

x <- rnorm(n)
y <- rnorm(n)
category <- sample(as.factor(1:class), size = n, replace = TRUE)

start_time <- Sys.time()
L <- myList(x = x, y = y, category = category)
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
# Time difference of 35.3367 secs
```

Comment: What have you tried? Which errors do you get?

Comment: ```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

template <typename WHAT>
class ListOf : public List {
public:
  template <typename T>
  ListOf( const T& x) : List(x){}

  WHAT operator[](int i){ return as<WHAT>( ( (List*)this)->operator[]( i) ) ; }

};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double sacha( ListOf<NumericMatrix> x) {
  double sum = 0.0 ;
  for( int i=0; i<x.size(); i++){
    sum += x[i](0,0) ;
  }
  return sum ;
}
```
The error I get is **reference to 'ListOf' is ambiguous**, **expected primary-expression before '>' token**

Comment: The dangerous of `using  namespace Rcpp;` ... Anyway, `ListOf<T>` is meanwhile part of Rcpp, so you can leave out the template definition. I am not sure if this helps with your code, though.

Comment: You are right! I can remove the template definition and the code is faster. But not as fast as I imagine. Is there other ways to make it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect two main problems concerning performance:

- Lots of string comparisons (of the order of `1e9`)
- Lots of cache misses for the matrices, since in general two consecutive xy-pairs won't be from the same category and will therefore need a different matrix

Both indicate into the same direction: Do not try to implement your own GROUP BY operations. Database engines and packages like `data.table` know better how to do that. For example, when using `data.table` we need a much simpler function that expects the x and y *for one category* and outputs a single matrix:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix getMat(NumericVector x, NumericVector y,
                     double xmin, double xmax, double ymin, double ymax,
                     int plot_width = 600, int plot_height = 600) {
    int n = x.size();
    NumericMatrix M(plot_height, plot_width);

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        int id_x = floor((x[i] - xmin)/(xmax - xmin) * (plot_width - 1));
        int id_y = floor((y[i] - ymin)/(ymax - ymin) * (plot_height - 1));
        M(id_y, id_x) += 1;
    }
    return M;
}

/***R
n <- 1e8
class <- 20

library("data.table")
foo <- data.table(x = rnorm(n),
                  y = rnorm(n),
                  category = sample(as.factor(1:class), size = n, replace = TRUE))

xmin <- min(foo$x)
xmax <- max(foo$x)
ymin <- min(foo$y)
ymax <- max(foo$y)

system.time(bar <- foo[,
                       list(baz = list(getMat(x, y, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))),
                       by = category])
*/
```

Notes:

- On my system the aggregation takes less than 6 seconds.
- It is even faster if one does a `setkey(foo, category)` before the aggregation. That physically alters the order of the rows, though. Use with care!
- `data.table` syntax is a bit terse, but one gets used to it ...
- The structure of the output is different, but can be converted if needed.